# RegisterClientScriptBlock is shown when i come back from browser

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint-2010

I am using SPGridView, I have one link button outside gridview that validates checkboxes in grid and are selected or not if there is no selected record then it will show us message like this from server side.

Code:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(
    this.GetType(), 
    "JSScript", 
    "<script language='javascript'>alert('Please Select at least one Document(s)');</script>");
```

i have some items in grid which by clicking on that i go to some other site collections doc libs.

issue scenario

- step 1. fire a validation message
- step 2. Navigate to some other site collections doc libs
- step 3. press back button of browser from  some other site collections doc libs

bug: it shows me again validation message from above.

pls help me

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to have a simple js onclick event on your link. Which will do the validation and if something is wrong will display the message.

The problem you are having is because when you use

**Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock** it registers your js alert message on the global level. So when you go back to the page its still there and gets executed again. You can try using the onclick event or when you navigate away from the page you need to remove your RegisterClientScriptBlock.

i.e.

```
Client.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(String), "JSScript", "");
```